# What does Aspect fit mean in ios

Tags: image, aspect-fit

I am studying a tutorial, and it says that we are going to set the image mode to aspect fit.

I wonder what that means?

I went to wikipeadia, and it is stated:

> The aspect ratio of an image describes the proportional relationship between its width and its height. It is commonly expressed as two numbers separated by a colon, as in 16:9. For an x:y aspect ratio, no matter how big or small the image is, if the width is divided into x units of equal length and the height is measured using this same length unit, the height will be measured to be y units.

so what I understood applying what i found on wikipedia that the aspect fit, **saves** the **same** aspect ratio of an image, but let it fit to its container. **is that true? **

if yes, in this case i would like to know on which axis it fits **first**

like let's say that the aspect ration of my image is 6:12, which means that if the width of the image is divided to 6 equal spaces, the hight of that image will be 12 equal species. but my questions is if the image is 6:12 and we changed its mode to aspect fit, does iOS give priority to the width (so it divided the width first to 6 and then makes the hight as 12 pecies?) or it first divides the height to 12 pieces and then makes the width as 6 pieces?

Answer (score 4):

Aspect fit is where the image is reduced (or enlarged) to fit within the size of the image view, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.

It's not that one axis is made to fit first. The image is reduced in size until both the height and width fit in the image view. This method will usually result in empty space surrounding the image either on the sides, or on the top and bottom. This empty space will exist unless the aspect ratio of the image happens to match the aspect ratio of the image view.